# Why imagemagick is reading/appending from text file in backward direction

Tags: bash, imagemagick

A sample file

> **file.txt**
>
> regenerated and later used again in the

images corresponding to each word present in that text file

> **and.png**
>
> [image: and.png]
>
> **used.png**
>
> [image: used.png]
>
> **append_row.png**
>
> [image: append_row.png]

Trying to append the images in the same sequence as they appear in text file

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        convert "$word".png append_row.png +append  append_row.png
    done
done
```

Output

> **append_row.png**
>
> [image: append_row.png]

Question : Why words are being appended in backward direction and how to append each word after the othher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join/append the two images `"$word".png` and `append_row.png` in that order in every iteration, adding each new word-image to the left of the already generate words.

You may want to swap those two arguments:

```
convert append_row.png "$word".png +append append_row.png
```